# Style of inline citations (numeric)

Tags: citation-style

In the paper that I am writing using LaTeX, I have several sentences like:

```
However, in \cite{aa2014} only a small uncertainty has been introduced ...
```

Or,

```
According to \cite{ab2014}, ...
```

Because I am forced to using numerical references, the result is respectively:

> However, in⁴ only a small uncertainty has been introduced ...
>
> According to⁸, ...

I don't like this style of citations so I am looking for improvements. I have been able to rewrite some of the sentences so that I can put the citation at the end of the sentence, but this does not always seems to be a good idea. Are there better options?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more appropriate for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mhwombat, I don't think it is, because my question is only about the style of inline citations, not about the actual LaTeX code.

Comment: If you're looking for a style suggestion, normally you use the style that the journal or conference you're submitting to prefers. In my field, CS, *numbered* citations usually appear in square brackets [5].

Comment: It is not clear from your question if the superscript-style citation is required by the publisher or if it is a choice of yours.

Comment: The superscript-style citation is required by the publisher. However, I don't like sentences such as: "According to⁸, ..." . So I am asking for suggestions to improve this style of inline citations.

Comment: @mhwombat: This question has nothing to do with LaTeX, and it is not more appropriate for TeX.SE.

Comment: @mhwombat: Also, even if this question were more appropriate for TeX.SE, it wouldn’t necessarily be off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question as asking for suggestions on which *.sty file to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that sentences like

> According to⁸

are horrible to read, although I recall seeing them a couple of times. A possible solution is to add author names:

> According to Alice and Bob⁸
>
> However, in Alice *et al*.⁴ only a small uncertainty has been introduced ...

Comment: Thank you, that indeed seems a good solution. Is there a way to automate the inclusion of the author names? That is, can I use something like: _According to \namesofauthors{aa2003} \cite{aa2003}_

Comment: @Pietair: that, yes, is a question for TeX.SE ;-) Anyway, the `natbib` package has the command `\citeauthor` for that purpose.